# Video Compression on Android devices

Tags: android

Is it possible to compress a large size video to a small size video before uploading it to a sever using Android?

This is the code I currently have.

```
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // video successfully recorded
            // preview the recorded video
            previewVideo();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using [FFmpeg 4 Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android&feature=search_result)
  and the explpanation is here [FFmpeg4Android usage](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)

Comment: Without FFmpeg is that possible

Comment: you can use silicompressor for best compression result
https://github.com/bhaskardonadapti5/SiliCompressor-master/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/iceteck/silicompressor